# In Infopath 2013, designing the sharepoint list form. Need Help

Tags: infopath-rules

**In Infopath 2013, designing the sharepoint list form, which has 5 Views, each  belong to different Department: IT, Marketing, Sales, Customer Care. 
Question**: When the Requester (User) submit the form, only the specific View should be sent to specific set of Users/team for the approval. => When they would Approve the same form, the requester should get auto notification email stating that "your request has been approved by _ _ _ Department". Need Help.

Praveen

Answer (score 0):

There are rules that run on from load that can change the view based on certain criteria that you specify.
The most basic being column values.  If a column = "value" then change to a specific view.
This is a nice way of doing it for linear forms that are always passed from one team to another but more challenging if you need to detect which department someone works for.
So I would either make the form process linear (pass from one team to another).
Or make it a single form but with collapsible sections so people only expand the parts of the form they are interested in.